# Why doesnt my Firefox/Firebug show me cached images?

Tags: firefox, caching, firebug

I'm looking at Firebug timeline of pages like www.google.com after page refresh (F5) and ALL the files are loaded with status 200 and no indication of them coming from cache.

In IE and chrome some of the files have status 304 not modified and cache seems to work.

Is there a setting somewhere telling firebug to not take files from cache?

Any other explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

Found it- my cache was off in about:config

Answer (score 0):

Firebug reports by looking at what is going on at a certain level of the application.

Caching of fresh entities (those that don't need to be revalidated) works by pretending to the higher level that it obtained the resources from the web even when it came from the cache, so that the next highest level doesn't have to care about caching (i.e. abstraction is used).

For this reason, Firebug sometimes reports as 200 cases where there was no request at all, though I have found that it does report 304s.

I'll use Firebug for a quick overview of timings, but for detailed reports on what's actually happening on the network I'd use Fiddler, which sits between the browser and the Internet and hence reports more directly on what actually got sent down the wire.

Comment: I had a colleague test it on his firebug and his shows 304s while my never does. There is some settings some where which is wrong for me. I need to find where it is

Comment: Do you have the same versions of firebug? I've seen the 304s for a while now. I still see 200s in cases where the file wasn't accessed at all though, so I still use fiddler instead (as handy as firebug is for other things).